# google cloud logging not working while working with python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

python code.

```
    import google.cloud.logging
    client = google.cloud.logging.Client.from_service_account_json("file.config")
    client.setup_logging()
    import logging

    loggin.info("error")
```

traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/baby/data-science/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
        return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/baby/data-science/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 923, in __call__
        return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
    File "/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/baby/data-science/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in _end_unary_response_blocking
        raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
    grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
        details = "The caller does not have permission"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1612798593.245379000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.71.42:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1062,"grpc_message":"The caller does not have permission","grpc_status":7}"
    >

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/baby/data-science/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/handlers/transports/background_thread.py", line 123, in _safely_commit_batch
        batch.commit()
    File "/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/baby/data-science/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/logger.py", line 383, in commit
        client.logging_api.write_entries(entries, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/baby/data-science/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/_gapic.py", line 121, in write_entries
        self._gapic_api.write_log_entries(
    File "/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/baby/data-science/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/gapic/logging_service_v2_client.py", line 476, in write_log_entries
        return self._inner_api_calls["write_log_entries"](
    File "/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/baby/data-science/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 145, in __call__
        return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/baby/data-science/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 281, in retry_wrapped_func
        return retry_target(
    File "/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/baby/data-science/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 184, in retry_target
        return target()
    File "/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/baby/data-science/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 214, in func_with_timeout
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/soubhagyapradhan/Desktop/upwork/baby/data-science/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
        six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
    File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
    google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 The caller does not have permission
```

Here i am trying to use google logging, But i am getting above error.
Please take a look

I am doing this using python. Is there any issue on generating service account creation

Comment: Which roles are assigned to the service account? You need at least `roles/logging.logWriter`. https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution to this issue? We recently had a Cloud Function start throwing the same exact error using this same setup as Kiran S. We tried a number of things including upping our google-cloud-logging version from 1.15.0 to 2.5.0 but the issue persists. And yes we checked that service-account has Log Writer permissions as well (yes it does).

Comment: same issue (using cloud-logging 2.6.0) even when I add Cloud Storage and Cloud Logging admin roles! In my case I have the issue using Vertex AI training job (no issue with default SA, issue with custom SA)

Answer (score 2):

I was using :

```
 client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
```

(not ".from_service_account_json")

and  I was getting the exact same error message. I also had the proper role `roles/logging.logWriter`. I am using using `cloud-logging 2.6.0`

I found that when I ran the code above in Vertex AI training job, if I don't create a client using my project_id in the following way:

```
 client = google.cloud.logging.Client(project=<user project number>)
```

then `google.cloud.logging` use some kind of dummy project_id i.e "i285ca2410679d8f1p-tp" which don't have the necessay access. Putting my project_id and all the error messages are then gone.

Answer (score 1):

As John said, have you checked if the Service Account has the proper role assigned? As the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python#run-gcp) says: "Using Cloud Logging library for Python requires the IAM Logs Writer role on Google Cloud. Most Google Cloud environments provide this role by default".

On the other hand, I am bit curious you used the "google-cloud-storage" tag, however you are not mention something related to it. Have you checked  if the issue is because you do not have the enough permissions (As Storage Admin) to access your bucket?